# Error 131:4 when running Photoshop CS5 with wine?

Tags: wine, adobe, photoshop

I installed Photoshop CS5 following the instructions on WineHQ, but receive the [131:4 error](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/855/cpsid_85519.html) with all of the CS5 programs. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: From the linked page, "This error occurs because of a missing file or invalid serial number". It also recommends trying a reinstall...have you done this?

Comment: And by "instructions on WineHQ", are you referring to [this page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20158)?

Comment: No, because I just copied all of the adobe files as shown in the [Wine tutorial](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20158). My Windows copy has a legal serial key and works fine. EDIT: Yes, that page. :)

Answer (score 0):

As it looks this is still a problem not resolved in Wine and from the look of the data provided by the last user test in Wine, in 1.5 it has other problems. Your only solution is to go back to the specific 1.3 version that had CS5 working (including the workaround to get it working) or wait for Wine to fix problems related to CS5.

I suggest to file a bug report in Wine and upvote CS5 to help development.